# Problem with Jaeger, logback and Sleuth working together

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing, jaeger

I was developing a Spring Boot application in which the loging is done by logback and Jaeger is integrated for instrumentation.

Myservice.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Myservice{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Myservice.class, args);
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
}

 @Bean
  public io.opentracing.Tracer jaegerTracer() {
    Builder builder = new Builder("Myservice",
        new RemoteReporter(new HttpSender(http://192.168.1.20:14268/api/traces), 10,
        65000, new Metrics(new StatsFactoryImpl(new NullStatsReporter()))),
        new ConstSampler(true))
        .registerInjector(Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new B3TextMapCodec())
        .registerExtractor(Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new B3TextMapCodec());
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration >
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName"
    source="spring.application.name" />
<appender name="consoleAppender" 
class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    <encoder 
class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "service": "${springAppName:-}",
                    "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                    "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
         </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Data Dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Oracle driver Dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- Opentracing with Jaeger Dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.31.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uber.jaeger</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaeger-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uber.jaeger</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaeger-b3</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logback Dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Jeager is properly connected to server and its getting the traces. The problem is with the logback logs. The traceId and spanId are not getting printed in the logs.

```
{"service" : "Myservice", "trace": "", "span":""}
```

But I myself found a solution for that. I added Spring Cloud Sleuth with my Spring Boot application.

```
    <!-- spring-cloud-sleuth dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Camden.SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now all the trace information was available in the logback log. But the problem is that Jaeger stopped registering traces to Jaeger server.

I tried Zipkin instead of Jaeger, but the same thing happened. What's wrong with my application? Is something wrong with the dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

You're using `Camden` release train with boot `2.0` and Sleuth `2.0`. That's completely incompatible. Please generate a project from start.spring.io from scratch, please don't put any versions manually for spring cloud projects, and please try again. Try using `Finchley` release train instead of `Camden`

Comment: I tried all versions of Finchley series. But the issue still there.

Comment: You have to add the opentracing brave bridge

Comment: Added dependency
               <dependency>
   <groupId>io.opentracing.brave</groupId>
   <artifactId>brave-opentracing</artifactId>
  </dependency>
But still traces are not displayed in Jaeger .

Comment: Are you sending the spans to Jaeger's Zipkin compatible endpoint?

Comment: Marcin ,You mean port 9411? I have tried with both 9411 and 14268. But no results.

Comment: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.6/getting-started/#migrating-from-zipkin have you set `--collector.zipkin.http-port=9411` ?